# Calculate the image and the kernel of the linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate the image(range) and the kernel of the linear transformation: $T:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\: T(a,\: b,\: c)=(a,\: b,\: 0)$.

**Attempt**

The kernel is
\begin{align*}
T(a,\: b,\: c)=(0,\: 0,\: 0)&\Leftrightarrow (a,\: b,\: 0)=(0,\: 0,\: 0)\\
&\Rightarrow a=0,\: b=0\\
&\Rightarrow Ker(T)=\left\lbrace (0,\: 0,\: 0) \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}
Or I think it is $(0, 0, c)$. I'm not sure, I got confused.
the image is
\begin{align*}
T(a,\: b,\: c)&=(a,\: b,\: 0)=(1,\: 0,\: 0)a+(0,\: 1,\: 0)b\\
&\Rightarrow R(T)=\left\lbrace (1,\: 0,\: 0),\: (0,\: 1,\: 0) \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel of the linear transformation is the set of points that is mapped to $(0,0,0)$. So $a$ and $b$ must be equal to zero, and $c$ can be any number. Therefore, the kernel is the set of all $(0,0,x)$, with $x$ any number.

You're correct that the image is generated by the basis vectors $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$